# Connecting to sql server 2005 from C# application problem

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can't get my *C#* app to connect to the *DB*.  I have tried numerous ways to connect. 
The *DB* is there. And, I can get to it through the sql server.  However, from within my code, I keep getting the following message:

> Error accessing the database, a
>   network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to sql server.  The sever
>   was not found or was not accessible. 
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that sql server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. Provider: sql network
>   interfaces, error 26 - error locating
>   server / instance specified. then also
>   error occured connection is not
>   open.my data source name is
>   aastha\sqlexpress.for  this reson
>   escape sequence not recognised.

Comment: It is a possible connectionstring problem! Try post it!

Comment: could you post your connection string

Comment: yeah post the connection string removing any passwords though

Comment: Please check your connection with the Server explorer in Visual Studio. You should be able to test the connection from there. Once the test is good, you may try to use the connection string generated in the server explorer. See more information on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to get a valid connectionstring.

1. create a new text document on your desktop
2. rename its extension from .txt to .udl
3. use wizard to connect to db
4. open .udl file in notepad
5. copy string
6. paste into connectionstring

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that you can connect to SQL Server using the same credentials of your application. Basically make sure that you have Windows and SQL Authentication enabled, **IF** you are using a SQL username.

If you are struggling with connection strings, please go here http://www.connectionstrings.com/ and find the one you need.